# javascript not passing strings with more than 1 word to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
...
results += "href=" + "JavaScript:" + "decrement(" + "'" + requestList[i].name + "'" +")>";
...
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=results;
```

The problem is when in the requestList[i].name is a string with more than 1 word, but with 1 word it works.
And when i inspect element in chrome and firefox, it only appears this:
Example: requestList[i].name = "John travolta";

```
<a href='JavaScript:decrement("John" travolta")>
```

And when i hover my mouse over the element:

```
JavaScript:increment("John
```

Any idea?

Comment: You are not writing the quotes in the `results` string. The browser is trying to guess them, but fails with whitespaces.

Comment: Your example code is mismatched.  You show "JavaScript:" + "decrement(", but then show the rendered output of "JavaScript:increment"

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. I've put an alert to print the requestList[i].name and it's printing the correct string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
results += "href=\"JavaScript:decrement('" + requestList[i].name + "')\">";
```

Your concatenation is confusing. Try to simplify it. Escape the `"` with `\"` in order to use `'` inside it, so your text will be nice no matter how much spaces it haves. The result will be:

```
href="JavaScript:decrement('John Travolta')">
```

So now you have to add the rest of your tag. Just a tip: Try to use your `a` tag with custom click like this:

```
href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="decrement('')"
```

I hope it helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you `console.log(results)`, you will see something like this:

```
<a href=JavaScript:decrement('John Travolta')>
```

Does this look like valid HTML to you? ;) Put quotes around attribute values.

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error here
`<a href='JavaScript:increment("John" travolta")>`'

remove the quote mark between 'John' and 'travolta'

Comment: That quote is auto-inserted by the Inspector as it attempts to make sense of the bad HTML given to it in the `results` variable.

Comment: as you see in example the first quote is single quote, insides are double

Comment: But do you see any double-quotes at all in the JavaScript that generates the HTML string?

Comment: I've commented on your answer:)